# How to get hold of graph from tf.function in tensorflow 2.0?

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

Previously, sess.graph was used as a handle to push things to tensorboard.

There is no current replacement AFAIK. Visualizing graphs is fundamental.

How can we viz graphs in tensorflow 2.0? Must be some hook into the functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tensorboard works in 2.0. [This example for keras](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorboard/blob/master/docs/r2/tensorboard_in_notebooks.ipynb) and [this without](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorboard/blob/master/docs/r2/image_summaries.ipynb)

Comment: The links are no longer valid.